# Problema con WHILE y con LISTAS

Tags: c++

No se que pasa la verdad, es un ejercicio simple de listas y el while me está fallando, no importa el valor que ingrese, no anda, sigue corriendo el programa y crea listas infinitas, ya probe cambiando el valor, poniendo distinto igual, y mil formas más, pero no se que podrá ser, si alguien me dice por qué, aunque ponga a otro = 0 sigue corriendo el programa, se lo agradecería mucho ;D

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Nodo
{
    int info;
    Nodo *sgte;
};

int main()
{
    int valor, otra=1;
    cout << "Ingrese el valor de la primer lista" << endl;
    cin >> valor;
    Nodo *lista=new Nodo();
    Nodo *paux=new Nodo();
    lista->info=valor;
    lista->sgte=new Nodo();
    paux = lista->sgte;
    while (otra=1)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el valor para la siguiente lista" << endl;
        cin >> valor;
        paux->info=valor;
        cout << "Quiere ingresar otra lista? Toque 1, si no, toque 0" << endl;
        cin >> otra;
        if (otra=1)
        {
            paux->sgte=new Nodo();
            paux=paux->sgte;
        }
        else
        {
            paux->sgte=NULL;

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En el while tienes puesto un =, y eso hace que sea una asignación y cierto siempre. Debes poner == para hacer la comparación. Lo mismo te ocurre en el if de crear un nuevo nodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

En la vida cotidiana existen dos tipos de operaciones en las que utilizamos la palabra "igual"

Si decimos:

```
x = 2;
```

Estamos diciendo que x obtiene el valor de 2, es decir estamos asignando el valor de `2` a `x`

Existe otro "igual" que es cuando comparamos dos cosas u objetos, en el lenguaje hablado también decimos: Si x es "igual" a 2, entonces...

Pero en programación es diferent, porque ahora no estamos asignando un valor, sino estamos comparando

Al comparar, como en el caso de un `if` tenemos que utilizar `==`

`if(x==2)` Se traduciria a lenguaje hablado como: Si `x` es equivalente/igual a `2` entonces...

Por lo que a tu código le hace falta poner los `==` en los `if` y funcionará

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Nodo
{
    int info;
    Nodo *sgte;
};

int main()
{
    int valor, otra=1;
    cout << "Ingrese el valor de la primer lista" << endl;
    cin >> valor;
    Nodo *lista=new Nodo();
    Nodo *paux=new Nodo();
    lista->info=valor;
    lista->sgte=new Nodo();
    paux = lista->sgte;
    while (otra==1)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el valor para la siguiente lista" << endl;
        cin >> valor;
        paux->info=valor;
        cout << "Quiere ingresar otra lista? Toque 1, si no, toque 0" << endl;
        cin >> otra;
        if (otra==1)
        {
            paux->sgte=new Nodo();
            paux=paux->sgte;
        }
        else
        {
            paux->sgte=NULL;

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No puedo creer que cometí un error tan estúpido y básico como ese, menos mal no me pasó en medio del parcial la puta madre jajajajjajaja, gracias :D